# How to cache iFrame Power BI (Javascript library)

Tags: javascript, iframe, powerbi, browser-cache, powerbi-embedded

I am using the JS library of Power BI on my website (https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) in Vue 2 project. I have a question - is it possible to cache the iframes, that I get?

So if I go to another tab and back it won't send new GET-Request, but take it from cache?

Answer (score 0):

In general, most browsers unless configured else are caching content, even those in iframes.

The cached data is mostly the scripts and sometimes the network responses that occurred during the embedding.
This can be configured not to happen either via code or by browser settings as caching policy.

Keep in mind that the cached Power BI Embedded data would not be useful after sometime, as data might get refreshed or changed.